# Why is the CSS animation display hide/block resets animation?

Tags: css, animation

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="anim_div">:D</div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#anim_div').addClass('animation');
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#parent').hide();
},1000);

setTimeout(function(){
    $('#parent').show();
},2000);
```

CSS:

```
#parent {
    width:400px;
    height:150px;
    border-right:1px solid red;
}
#anim_div {
    position:absolute;
}
.animation {
    -webkit-animation:anim 4s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes anim {
    0% {
       left:0px; 
    }
    100% {
        left:400px;
    }
}
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/o7bt7p3a/

Is there any way to stop animation repeat/reset after hiding and showing parent element **via css only**?

Comment: Currently removing animation class via setTimeout, but it's kinda ugly... These transition events is not a solution too. :\ Too much pain... :D

Comment: Not tested, but what happens if you use `opacity` or `visibility` instead of show/hide? Are solutions involving them acceptable? Say something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/o7bt7p3a/1/).

Comment: Guess this is the only solution, if no other solutions. :\ Have to edit old code because of that. :D

Comment: There is a property called `animation-play-state` (or something similar) which can be set to `pause` but it has to be tied to the show/hide option and so it would be better to do it via JS.

Comment: I was only going to do: **-webkit-animation:anim 4s 1;** and so it only occurs once?

Comment: Not working. It's starting from beginning each time your hide/show parent element.

Comment: @Somebody: True, just now checked. But the difference between using `animation-play-state` and the first fiddle that I posted is that, in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/o7bt7p3a/2/) the animation restarts from the same place after the opacity comes back to 1 whereas in the first, it is still moving in the background.

Comment: I'm not sure whether it's a feature or a bug...

Comment: It is a feature because in the first sample, we are only hiding the parent using `opacity` and doing nothing to stop the animation whereas in the second we are actually pausing it at the precise position where it was when the time-out happened.

Comment: Hello it seems there is no specific way to do prevent this, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37664508/stop-animation-from-replaying-when-parent-switches-from-displaynone-to-block).

Answer (score 3):

Sorry I didn't quite understand the question earlier.

Basically, jQuery's `hide`/`show` toggles the target element's `display` value between `none` and it's original value. See [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/css.js#L153-L210).

This means the element is *removed* from the render tree and losts all its animation states. When you toggle it back, animations you define will be applied to it from the very begining.

To prevent this, you probably need to toggle the CSS `visibility` value instead of using jQuery's `hide`/`show`.

To achieve what you were trying to do, check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g63a48xw/).

Comment: @Justineo  visibility:hidden means that unlike display:none, the tag is not visible, but space is allocated for it on the page. Not a solution.

Comment: Obviously `display: none` is not intentional here, so it's unnecessary to provide solution under such premise.

Comment: Thanks for this, exactly the solution I am looking for! I was using display: none, and switching it to visibility: hidden with height: 0 solved the animation resetting every time I display: block the element