# Stop animation from replaying when parent switches from display:none to block

Tags: css, css-animations

I have a set of tabs that each contain a child element that animates. What happens when I click each tab is that the animation of the child element within the tab runs. I do not want it to run. I want the animation to run the first time then not replay when it's parent switch from `display:none` to `display:block`.

In the example I made below I have 2 parent divs, each with a child div that animates over to the right. When each parent is set to block the animation replays, I do not want that to happen. I want each child to stay positioned over to the right. How can I make that happen?

```js
$(".toggler").on("click", function() {
  $(".parent").toggleClass("active");
});
```

```css
.parent {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  animation: move 200ms cubic-bezier(.91, .8, .54, 1.39);
}
.active {
  display: block;
}
.child.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.child.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
@keyframes move {
  from {
    left: 0;
  }
  to {
    left: 180px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="toggler">Click this</a>

<div class="parent active">
  <div class="child red"></div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child blue"></div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/y21khujy/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, animations will restart every time the `display` value is changed from `none` to something else.

As per [W3C Spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/): (emphasis is mine)

> Setting the display property to ‘none’ will terminate any running animation applied to the element and its descendants. ***If an element has a display of ‘none’, updating display to a value other than ‘none’ will start all animations applied to the element by the ‘animation-name’ property***, as well as all animations applied to descendants with display other than ‘none’.

There is no direct way to prevent this from happening because that *is* the intended behavior. You can workaround the situation by using other methods to hide the element instead of using `display: none`.

Following are a few suggestions on how the element could be hidden without `display: none`. It is not mandatory to use only one of the following workarounds, it could be some other way also as long as it doesn't involve changing the `display` property of the element.

- Using `height: 0`, `width: 0`, `overflow: hidden` to hide the element.

  ```js
  $(".toggler").on("click", function() {
    $(".parent").toggleClass("active");
  });
  ```

  ```css
  .parent {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .child {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    animation: move 200ms cubic-bezier(.91, .8, .54, 1.39) forwards;
  }
  .active {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    overflow: visible;
  }
  .child.red {
    background-color: red;
  }
  .child.blue {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  @keyframes move {
    from {
      left: 0;
    }
    to {
      left: 180px;
    }
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <a class="toggler">Click this</a>

  <div class="parent active">
    <div class="child red"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child blue"></div>
  </div>
  ```
- Adding a container, using `position: absolute` and `opacity: 0` to hide the element.

  ```js
  $(".toggler").on("click", function() {
    $(".parent").toggleClass("active");
  });
  ```

  ```css
  .container {
    position: relative;
  }
  .parent {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .child {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    animation: move 200ms cubic-bezier(.91, .8, .54, 1.39) forwards;
  }
  .active {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  .child.red {
    background-color: red;
  }
  .child.blue {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  @keyframes move {
    from {
      left: 0;
    }
    to {
      left: 180px;
    }
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <a class="toggler">Click this</a>

  <div class='container'>
    <div class="parent active">
      <div class="child red"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="parent">
      <div class="child blue"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  ```
- Adding a container, using `position: absolute` and `visibility: hidden` to hide the element.

  ```js
  $(".toggler").on("click", function() {
    $(".parent").toggleClass("active");
  });
  ```

  ```css
  .container {
    position: relative;
  }
  .parent {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .child {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    animation: move 200ms cubic-bezier(.91, .8, .54, 1.39) forwards;
  }
  .active {
    visibility: visible;
  }
  .child.red {
    background-color: red;
  }
  .child.blue {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  @keyframes move {
    from {
      left: 0;
    }
    to {
      left: 180px;
    }
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <a class="toggler">Click this</a>

  <div class='container'>
    <div class="parent active">
      <div class="child red"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="parent">
      <div class="child blue"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  ```
- Adding a container, using `position: absolute` and `z-index` to hide the element.

  ```js
  $(".toggler").on("click", function() {
    $(".parent").toggleClass("active");
  });
  ```

  ```css
  .container {
    position: relative;
  }
  .parent {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .child {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    animation: move 200ms cubic-bezier(.91, .8, .54, 1.39) forwards;
  }
  .active {
    z-index: 1;
  }
  .child.red {
    background-color: red;
  }
  .child.blue {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  @keyframes move {
    from {
      left: 0;
    }
    to {
      left: 180px;
    }
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <a class="toggler">Click this</a>

  <div class='container'>
    <div class="parent active">
      <div class="child red"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="parent">
      <div class="child blue"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  ```